# How to count the number of event based on JSON field structure in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

I want to count the number of occurrence of a specific JSON structure. For example in my event there is a field called `data` which its value is JSON . but this field can have a variety of structures. like:

```
data = {a: "b"}
data= {d: "x", h: "e"} 
...
```

now I want to know how many event has data with each JSON structure and I don't care about values only keys are matter.

Comment: do you have any *full* sample events you can share?

Comment: is this not clear? I just care about data field in my events, which can have 3 different JSON data. different keys/structure

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these 2:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp data=*
| stats dc(data) as unique_data
```

Or

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp data=*
| stats values(data) as data_vals
```